# how do I make this window close in java?

Tags: java, window, awt

I've already this project, but I'm having more problems. The dialog for SetMusicDialog opens, but it won't close when I try to exit out. I have a System.exit, but I'm not sure why the window won't close.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SetMusicDialog extends Dialog
{
  public static String sng;
  public SetMusicDialog()
  {

    super ((Dialog)null, "Set Music");
     Panel mpanel;
     Font l = new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 12);
      setFont(l);//sets font
      setBackground(Color.cyan);

      Panel f = new Panel();
      f.add("West", new Button("Death Grips"));
      f.add("East", new Button("Siren"));
      add("South",f);
      pack();                           // make it just fit
      resize(preferredSize());
      move(200,200);
  }
  public boolean handleEvent1 (Event evt)
  {
    switch (evt.id)
    {
      case Event.WINDOW_DESTROY:
        System.exit(0);
        dispose();
        return true;
      case Event.ACTION_EVENT:
        if("Death Grips".equals(evt.arg))
      {
        sng= "breakmirrors.wav";
      }
      else if("Siren".equals(evt.arg))
      {
       sng= "bip.wav";
      }
      dispose();
     }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using AWT, you will need to use a `WindowListener`, see [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html). I however highly recommend not using AWT if you can and use Swing instead, which provides a `defaultCloseOperation` property for `JFrame` and `JDialog`

Comment: I'll try, I did it somehow without using a WindowListener before but I can't seem to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

`windowClosed` **won't detect if the user tries to close the window**. It will only run if the window has been closed. So use `windowClosing`.

Also, by using `WindowAdapter` you **do not** need to write all the methods of `WindowListener`.

I added this code in your constructor, and it works properly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AWT, you should create a `WindowListener` as MadProgrammer stated.  Basically, a WindowListener is a class that has methods that are run when certain window-related actions occur.  To write code that will run when a `Dialog` (which extends `Window`) is closed:

```
//d is a dialog

d.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

    //You'll need to implement all the abstract methods.  leave them empty.

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        //Your code
    }

});
```

Basically, you're anonymously implementing the abstract class `WindowEvent`.  Make sure you implement all the other methods too, or you will get compiler errors.  Your IDE should automatically implement all the methods.